How do I correctly determine NAME_MAX for shm_open?
In the manual page for shm_open, we see that the argument for the name parameter should be up to NAME_MAX characters long for portable use.
However, in The GNU C Library Reference Manual's section entitled "Limits on File System Capacity" we see that NAME_MAX is not defined in "limits.h" on a system if it "allows different file systems or files to have different limits. We are told to use pathconf instead.
However, pathconf requires an actual path (or file descriptor) to use. What path should we use for shared memory objects as used by shm_open. From what I understand, this is handled internally by glibc. On Linux, it is often, but not necessarily, "/dev/shm".
I would prefer not to use 255 directly as mentioned in the manual page for shm_open. It doesn't seem like a good idea to just use "/" since "/dev/shm" is often tmpfs, which differs from the root file system.
I tried grepping the header files and the output of getconf -a and looking through other related manual pages, but I don't see anything on how to do this.
I tracked down the code that opens a shared memory object in glibc but that was fairly unhelpful since it's basically hard-coded.

https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c
https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.h
https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm-directory.c

Maybe that means I'm underestimating how portable "/dev/shm" is?

If the system implements the XSI extension, NAME_MAX has to be at least _XSI_NAME_MAX, which is 255.

OTOH, _POSIX_NAME_MAX is just 14, presumably because that was the filename limit on early versions of Unix. AFAIK, every ignores this possibility and assumes long filenames are allowed these days.


In the manual page for shm_open, we see that the argument for the name parameter should be up to NAME_MAX characters long for portable use.

Yes, it does.  And it pretty much lies, as far as the current version of POSIX goes.  What POSIX used to say was

The name argument conforms to the construction rules for a pathname. [...] If name does not begin with the slash character, the effect is implementation-defined. The interpretation of slash characters other than the leading slash character in name is implementation-defined.

The limitation to NAME_MAX, the maximum length of a path segment, can reasonably be interpreted as implied by name

having the form of a path,
with a leading slash and no other slashes

as meets requirements and avoids explicit implementation-definedness.
However, the latest version of POSIX now adds:

the length limits for the name argument are implementation-defined and need not be the same as the pathname limits {PATH_MAX} and {NAME_MAX}.

I'm unsure what the point of that change (clarification?) was, as it leaves programmers hanging in the wind, and I don't see how it's much help to implementations.
Even when we thought we had NAME_MAX to rely on here, however, the relevant portability concern was not the NAME_MAX of the current system, but rather the smallest NAME_MAX of any system on which your code must run. Even if you have more leeway than that on some systems, you need to be prepared to do with the minimum, so you may as well just do that everywhere.  That takes runtime pathconf out of the picture.
Of course, we can't evaluate what NAME_MAX may be on every past, present, and future system.  However, the appropriate context for considerations of portable use of this POSIX function is POSIX implementations, and POSIX defines a minimum acceptable value: _POSIX_NAME_MAX, which is 14. Even though that is not conclusive, what you should take from this is that POSIX allows the limit to be very small.

However, in The GNU C Library Reference Manual's section entitled "Limits on File System Capacity" we see that NAME_MAX is not defined in "limits.h" on a system if it "allows different file systems or files to have different limits.

If GLibc in fact fails to define NAME_MAX for any particular system then it is not POSIX compliant for that system.  POSIX makes some similar comments about the constansts possibly being unsuitable for some uses, but it specifies that they are defined in all cases.  But if portability is your aim, however, then it's immaterial.  As already described, that requires you to focus on the smallest length limit among all the systems you want to support.  If you can be sure of satisfying that then you don't need to perform a runtime check.

We are told to use pathconf instead.

Yes and no.  POSIX says that it is unspecified whether the names of shared memory objects appear in the filesystem, and pathconf / fpathconf inquire about filesystem characteristics.  As long as we're talking about portability, then, we cannot interpret POSIX to be presenting pathconf as a portable means for determining the local limit here.  It seems like it might work on systems where those names do appear on the filesystem, but I don't think that Glibc's documentation is necessarily meant to apply to special filesystems such as /dev.
If you do rely on that, then you're also relying on its existence, which narrows the scope of your portability concerns enough that you probably don't need to go to all the trouble in the first place.

However, pathconf requires an actual path (or file descriptor) to use. What path should we use for shared memory objects as used by shm_open.

POSIX does not guarantee that there is any path you can use for that purpose, and that's probably the wrong idea anyway. Keep your shared memory names small, and document the maximum you use.  This is a limit on the portability of your program.  In practice, you're unlikey to run into any system where 255 bytes is too large, though it's not out of the question that you would do.

Why wouldn't a runtime check work? Shouldn't it return 14 on such limited systems?

@A.Bear, it's not that a runtime check necessarily couldn't be done, though in fact, I don't think it can be on systems that do not expose shared memory identifiers via the filesystem.  The main thing I want to get across here is that a runtime check is the wrong thing to do to provide for portability.  Consider: if a runtime check determines that the shared memory name you want to use is too long, then where do you go from there? If you can get away with a shorter name then you could have used that shorter one in the first place.  Otherwise, the only thing to do is fail.

Where I go from there is to not allocate and fill as much memory with a name. Using a longer name, decreases the probability of a collision on systems which do support it. In practice, it's not worth the complexity, but it is the theoretical optimum and that's what I wanted to know.

@A.Bear, you initially asked about portability.  Now you are asking about optimization, which is quite different, and even somewhat opposed.  In truth, I'm not sure there is really an optimization angle here, but in any case, as I have already conveyed, POSIX does not define a mechanism for determining what the local limit on shared memory name lengths is.  You have to depend on implementation-specific characteristics or documentation.  Pragmatically, your best bet is to just keep your shared memory names small, and this is not usually a burden.

I was asking about optimal portability in both cases.
